# How can I get a list of existing cross-object references without hitting the limit?

Tags: formula, governorlimits, limits, object

I am auditing our org - I'm aware that we're close to the cross-object reference limit on OppLineItem and Asset because we've hit it before, but have been able to rationalise various rules, formulas etc to bring down the number.

I'd simply like to know if/how I can get the list of existing cross-object references without having to create something which hits the limit and returns the errors message with list.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried this: `CreatedBy.Profile.CreatedBy.Profile.CreatedBy.Profile.CreatedBy.Profile.CreatedBy.Profile.CreatedBy.Profile.Name` It has more than 10 reference and it's working fine...

Answer (score 2):

Currently the easiest way to do this is to start to create a new formula field on the object where you think you might hit the limit. For the formula value, enter a formula that has 10* cross-object references in it, such as:

```
CreatedBy.Profile.CreatedBy.Profile.CreatedBy.Profile.CreatedBy.Profile.CreatedBy.Profile.Id
```

Then click the "Check Syntax" button in the formula editor. It will give you a message stating, "You have reached the maximum number of 10 object references on account. You must remove at least *n* relationships to save this formula field."

Since you have 10 references in your formula field, *n* will be the number of references you currently have without the formula field. You can then cancel out without saving the field.

*If your org limit is something other than 10, create a formula that has as many cross-object references as you have in your org. Usually I use the field picker and keep hitting Created By > Profile until I can't select any more.